# Scanner Exception Retry

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

How to make scanner retry when exception occur?
Consider this app running on CLI mode.

Example:

```
System.out.print("Define width: ");
    try {
        width = scanner.nextDouble();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("That's not a number!");
        //width = scanner.nextDouble(); // Wrong code, this bring error.
    }
```

If the user not inputting `double` type input, then the error thrown. But i want after the error message appears. It's should be asking the user input the *width* again.

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want the program to ask the user to re-enter a right input after it fails. In that case you can do something like:

```
boolean inputOk = false;
while (!inputOk) {
    System.out.print("Define width: ");
    try {
        width = scanner.nextDouble();
        inputOk = true;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.err.println("That's not a number!");
        scanner.nextLine();   // This discards input up to the 
                              // end of line
        // Alternative for Java 1.6 and later
        // scanner.reset();   
    }
}
```

Note: you should *only* catch and retry for a `InputMismatchException`.  The `nextXxx` methods throw other exceptions, and if you attempt to retry those, your application will go into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly,i have double checked

```
        Scanner in;
        double width;

          boolean inputOk = false;
          do
          {

               in=new Scanner(System.in);
              System.out.print("Define width: ");
                  try {
                      width = in.nextDouble();
                      System.out.println("Greetings, That's a number!");
                      inputOk = true;
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                      System.out.println("That's not a number!");
                      in.reset();

                  }
          }
          while(!inputOk);
    }
```