# Java Exception Handling - Do while Loop

Tags: java, exception

I'm writing a Java Exception Handling program and encountered following issue.

when I enter a invalid input an infinite loop started executing instead of execution start from the try block.

```
public class Exception_Handling {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean bl=true;
        do {

        try {
            int a = sc.nextInt();
            int b = sc.nextInt();
            bl=false;
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Enter Valid Number Format");
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        }while(bl);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner Exception Retry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857338/scanner-exception-retry)

Answer (score 3):

You need to flush your buffer before re-entering in the loop. Otherwise java tries to read the same input again and again.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exception_Handling {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean bl = true;
        do {

            try {
                int a = sc.nextInt();
                int b = sc.nextInt();
                bl = false;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Enter Valid Number Format");
                System.out.println(ex);
                sc.next();
            }
        } while (bl);
    }   
}
```

You can also use `sc.reset()` instead of `sc.next()`in your case. But if you had configured scanner with `useDelimiter`, `useLocale` or `useRadix` it will reset these parameters too. (see [reset()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#reset--) java doc)

Answer (score 0):

You have a catch exception on `Input Mismatch` so it won't bother to execute this statement:

`bl = false;`

which would not terminate the loop.

```
public class Exception_Handling {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean bl=true;
    do {

    try {
        bl=false;
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();

    }
    catch(InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.println("Enter Valid Number Format");
        System.out.println(ex);

    }
    }while(bl);
}   

}
```